# How can I get a top element like a preceding of an element on xpath?

Tags: html, css, web, xpath

I need to get the father node of an element but specifying  some attributes of then, not using indexes

My scenario is this

```
<div class="flockToUnlock section">
    <flock-to-unlock>
        <div class="xpto">
```

And my xpath is

```
//preceding::flock-to-unlock//div[@class='xpto']
```

I want to get the node `<div class="flockToUnlock section">` but I'm getting the `<div class='xpto'>`

Comment: You specify `//div[@class'xpto']`, which is why you're getting the div with that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing syntax errors, this XPath expression `//preceding::flock-to-unlock//div[@class='xpto']` is read as:

> *"from any node in the tree, navigate to all preceding `flock-to-unlock` elements and then to all descendant `div` with
>   `class` attribute equal to `'xpto'`"*

This is a very convoluted transversal of the document. If the presence of `flock-to-unlock` and `div` with `class` attribute equal to `"xpto"` are the conditions to select, just use:

```
//div[flock-to-unlock//div[@class='xpto']]
```